# jQuery click twice to function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use `jQuery` to update an anchor tag that takes the user back to the top of the page. The link will display if the content on the page is greater than the `height` of page itself. If the content is not greater that the page itself, the link will not display.

The `height` of the content element is dependent on the content returned, from the link in my `nav`. So, on link click, I get the height of the content element and determine if I need to show the "back to top" link.

It works, but the problem is you have to click the `nav` tab twice for it to work.

**jQuery code :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[data-toggle]").click(function() {
        var pct = Math.round(( $("div.tab-content").outerHeight(true) / $(window).height() ) * 100);
        if (pct > 90) {
            $("#top-link").text("Back to top");
        } else {
            $("#top-link").empty();
        }
    });
});
```

**Navigation code :**

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#configs" >Configs</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#error-log" >Error Log</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#user-log" >User Log</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**Content element :**

```
<main>
    <div class="tab-content">
        This area is populated with data depending on the nav link clicked.
    </div>
</main>
```

**"back to top" link :**

```
<a id="top-link" href="#top"></a>
```

Thank you in advance for assistance with fixing this so that it functions on the first click.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rv5m50eg/)

Comment: Could you possibly add a `snippet` or `fiddle` and recreate this scenario?

Comment: question updated. fiddle added.

Comment: when you goto the fiddle, click on tab 1, scroll to the bottom of the page and notice there is no link to go back to the top. then click tab 1 again, and the link will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem being is that your calculation would happen earlier before the contents are rendered and hence wrong value was taken into your `if condition` within `click event`. What I would suggest is that, you don't need `click event` to set/clear `back-to-top` text. Instead you can use **[`shown.bs.tab`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events)** event of `bootstrap tab` and perform the operation once the `tab` is shown. Below would be your `JS` updated code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
});

$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function(e) {
  var pct = Math.round(($("div.tab-content").outerHeight(true) / $(window).height()) * 100);
  if (pct > 90) {
    $("#top-link").text("Back to top");
  } else {
    $("#top-link").empty();
  }
});
```

## [Here's the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/rv5m50eg/2/)

As part of suggestion, I would like to suggest you that instead of **setting and clearing the text**, you could just use `.hide` and `.show` into `#top-link` element, as in `$("#top-link").show()` and `$("#top-link").hide()`.

**## Demo for that**

Comment: Thank you so much for finding where I was going wrong and the suggestion. Both work fantastically.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

@L-Train Do you have google chrome where you can check to make sure you don't have any errors on your codes? Can you do the inspect element by right clicking on your mouse?

Comment: it should be in comments  area

Comment: Yes, I have chrome and/or other browsers that offer that functionality. I have gone in and checked in the console area and no errors pertaining to the script in question are shown.